# What is the best way to get encoded base64 string data that is stored in s3 as png files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encoding, boto3

Background:
I have s3 paths that is including png/jpeg images in S3. I want to convert this images into base64 during python run time. I wanted to improve the current implementation because I have large files and I don't really need to download the file that I only want to get encoded information. I was thinking some alternative solution, but some document mentioned that for large data, get_object() can be slower, but doesn't give me a clear understanding when it can be slower.

Current Implementation:

1. Using download_file() from S3 download the images.
2. Then encode it on my side.

Alternative solution I'm thinking:

1. Use get_object() and read() which returns in byte format
2. decode('utf-8') and encode to base64.

Question:

What exactly happens behind when I use get_object()? Does it actually work same as download_file() which means download the object? This solution can be slower when their are large data?

Comment: So  the images are stored on S3, but you want to encode them on the fly - that's a pretty straightforward task. What have you tried yourself? What problem did you run into? As for your second question, accessing with the S3 path without splitting it - it appears `boto3` requires bucket and key separately, but splitting the path accordingly is a quick single line statement - what problem are you having with that?

Comment: @Grismar I'm not familiar with the S3 boto3. For the first one, it seems I need to use download_obj, so I was asking is there other method that giving me the encoded image directly or giving me the option of downloading type such as base64 string type. - I didn't face any problem, I'm looking for more efficient way to process this.

Comment: @Grismar  For the second one, I know boto3 requires bucket and key, and it seems I cannot use S3 path directly. But since I'm not familiar with this and some of documents are outdated, I wanted to make sure I'm not missing other methods that allowing to use s3 path to access the s3 bucket.

Comment: Although it would be possible for a library like `boto3` to offer you to encode its output on the fly, it's not really `boto3`'s job, since there's no need to encode it before sending it over the internet. `boto3` is well-designed in that it expects you to apply any encoding you like to the output and it wouldn't be too complicated to encode the data on the fly in a file-like object that could be passed to `s3.download_fileobj`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the encoding isn't really needed for anything `boto3` needs to do, it doesn't offer that as an option. You can just encode the content on the fly yourself:

```
import base64
import io
import boto3


class Base64Encoder(io.IOBase):
    def __init__(self, fileobj):
        self.fileobj = fileobj

    def write(self, b):
        return self.fileobj.write(base64.b64encode(b))


# some code that sets things up
...
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# download from S3, encode to base64 on the fly, and write to wherever you need it
with whatever_gets_your_file_like_target() as f:
    s3.download_fileobj('mybucket', 'mykey', Base64Encoder(f))
```

Since you didn't provide information on where you actually need to write that base64 encoded content, I'm just calling `whatever_gets_your_file_like_target()` here.

Edit: you modified your question and added "What exactly happens behind when I use get_object()? Does it actually work same as download_file() which means download the object? This solution can be slower when their are large data?"

Yes and no. Yes, it does work more or less the same as `.download_fileobj()` if you go and read the stream from `result['Body']`, which is what you would do to encode it as base64. But no, it only gets all the attributes for the object, it doesn't start streaming the content unless you access the stream.

For a very large file, if you're only interested in some of the metadata, you would use `.get_object()` to avoid needlessly downloading the entire file. On the other hand, if you just want the content, encode it, and send it somewhere, you could use `.download_fileobj()` - which is why that was the original answer.

Since your question was about encoding the contents of the object in base64, it doesn't matter all that much here. If you use `.get_object()`, you have a bit of overhead from starting the stream separately, and getting a bunch of metadata you may end up not even using. If you need some of that though, getting it with `.get_object()` and then streaming the content makes sense. You didn't share any of that information in your question, so the answer has to assume.

Comment: Note that if you do this you'll likely end up with embedded base64 padding characters that you need to deal with depending on the decoder.  Notably, the Python decoder will stop at the first padding sequence it finds.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is actually similar to my current implementation. I updated my question to make more clear of my question

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an answer to the follow-on question. If you have more questions, you should ask a new one and either accept the answer with the checkmark (if it does indeed answer your question) or perhaps close this question (although I wouldn't recommend that, since it's not a pointless one).